# Rails - WebSocket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, redis

I want to push data to client using WebSocket. I dont now how to return data(from Redis) to client. Could somebody explain me that?

sockets_controller.rb

```
class SocketsController < WebsocketRails::BaseController
  def create
    send_message :new_event, {:message => 'TEST'}
  end
end
```

events.rb

```
WebsocketRails::EventMap.describe do
  subscribe :new_event, 'sockets#create'
end
```

websocket_rails.rb

```
WebsocketRails.setup do |config|
  config.redis_options = { driver: :ruby }
  config.standalone = false
  config.synchronize = true
end
```

Client side:

```
$socket.on('test', function(data) {
console.log(data);
    $scope.events.upshift(data);
if($scope.events.length>50){
$scope.events.length=50;
EventsList =$scope.events;
}
});

routerApp.config(["$socketProvider", function ($socketProvider) {
  $socketProvider.setUrl("http://172.16.20.179:3000/events");
}]);
```

On the client side issue looks like:

```
GET http://172.16.20.179:3000/socket.io/?
EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1439215071732-9

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://172.16.20.179:3000/socket.io/?
EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1439215056291-6. No 'Access-Control-Allow-
Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 
'http://localhost:4000' is therefore not allowed access. The response 
had HTTP status code 404.
```

Comment: Please provide your source code.

Comment: Add your client code too.

Comment: Done, you can take a look now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to use `Socket.IO` for web-sockets. There are no supported implementation of `Socket.IO` for Rails.

If you want an example on how to interact with websocket-rails from Angular.JS, you can use, for example, the following guide:

https://medium.com/@karimbutt/integrating-websocket-rails-with-angularjs-or-other-js-frameworks-256729e95a86

Comment: are you sure its impossible?

Comment: Well, you can set up additional Node.js server as shown here: http://mikeatlas.github.io/realtime-rails/

Comment: Now I get 
GET http://172.16.20.179:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1439276851829-54 404 (Not Found)